# Puppeteer simple form login

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

My Puppeteer code is as follows. I am trying to log in into my broadbad page which triggers every day. I tried curl command but it just fails. So I am now trying node js puppeteer.

**login.js**

```
// example from github.com login page 
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const screenshot = 'broadband.png';
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true, ignoreHTTPSErrors: true})
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('https://server-ip-address/userportal/login.do?requesturi=http%3A%2F%2F1.254.254.254%2F%3F')
  await page.type('input[type="username"]', process.env.BB_USER)
  await page.type('input[type="password"]', process.env.BB_PWD)
  await page.click('[name="lesubmit"]')

  await page.waitForNavigation()
  await page.screenshot({ path: screenshot })
  browser.close()
  console.log('See screenshot: ' + screenshot)
})()
```

I ran it as follows

```
BB_USER='my_username' BB_PWD='my_password' node login.js
```

But it always says

> Error: No node found for selector: input[type="username"]

Here is my actual broadband login from:

```
        <div class="formBox">
            <h2>Login to your account</h2>
            <form name="form1" action="">
                <font color="red" size="2">
                 </font>
                <label>Service Type</label>
                 <select name="type"><option value="1">Check Account Details</option>
                    <option value="2" selected="selected">Internet Access</option></select>             
                <label>User Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" value="">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" value=""><br />
                <input type="hidden" id="rememberme" name="rememberme"/>
                <div style="background:#f1f6f9; height:40px; margin:10px 0 0 0; padding:15px 0 0 0; border-top:1px solid #dedede;">
                    <a href='/userportal/forgotpasswd.do'>Forgot Password?</a>
                    <input type="button" name="lesubmit" id="ptype" class="btn-primary" value="Login" onclick="return savesettings();" />
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Honestly, I don't know how to choose selector in this case. I thought `name="username"` is sufficient but it is not. Can you provide some hints?

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to SF!

Target `'input[name="username"]'` instead of `'input[type="username"]'`.
Like so:

```js
await page.type('input[name="username"]', process.env.BB_USER)
```

### Explanation

In your example, the target HTML is

```html
<input type="text" name="username" value="">`
```

So the correct selector would be:

```css
input[name='username']
```

Which matches the `name` property which is present on the target HTML element (`<input name='username'>`)

Your original code was `input[type='username']`, which would match an `<input>` with the property `type='username'`. However, the targeted element has `type='text'`, not `type='username'`, so the selector doesn't match, and Puppeteer informs you that it could not find a matching element: `No node found for selector: input[type="username"]`

> The reason the username input has `type='text'` is that the input `type` property determines [which form control the browser renders](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#%3Cinput%3E_types) (text, number, dates, checkboxes, etc.). As usernames are typically text, the username field used `type='text'`